# Python 3.x and SFTP

Tags: python-3.x, sftp

I know that the `Paramiko` api exists for Python 2.x.  Is there an emerging method for interacting with a remote server using `SFTP` functions from within a Python 3.1 script?  Extensive searching of the `paramiko` site uncovered no evidence of 3.x support.
If not, I will either use Python-2.x with `Paramiko` for my remote access, or maybe just use `subprocess.popen()` or similar with Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with not being able to install paramiko for some reason (don't remember now), and implemented a wrapper for putty's SFTP implmentation, it's in python 2.x, but you may be able to get some reference value from it.

http://psftplib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/psftplib.py

Comment: Thanks monkut, the code is interesting.  I'm on Linux and I am struggling with the native sftp (some buffering issue that even bufsize=1 doesn't solve).  I think I may give up on Python 3.x for this part of the project (maybe keep 3.x for the other parts) and I'll try Python 2.x/Paramiko next.  Thanks for your answer!